# Mudando opacidade de um form através de outro

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso mudar a opacidade do form principal toda vez que o usuário clica no botão fechar. Quando ele clica nesse botão a opacidade fica em `this.Opacity = .75;` e abre-se um novo form perguntando se ele deseja fechar o programa.

Botão fechar no form principal:

```
private void btFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = .75;
        fechar f = new fechar();
        f.ShowDialog();
        f.Dispose();
    }
```

O problema é que quando o usuário clica para não fechar o sistema no form "fechar" a opacidade do form principal não volta para `this.Opacity = 1;`

Botão para não fechar o programa:

```
public void btFecharNAO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        principal p = new principal();
        p.Opacity = 1;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passe a `tela principal` como parâmetro para o `form` `fechar`, na chamada do construtor. Algo semelhante a isto:

```
public partial class fechar : Form
{
    private Form mFormParent = null;
    public fechar(Form frmParent){
          this.mFormParent  = frmParent;
    }

    //seu código

    public void btFecharNAO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (mFormParent != null)
           mFormParent.Opacity = 1;
       this.Close();
    }
}
```

E na chamada basta passar o próprio form como parâmetro:

```
private void btFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = .75;
    fechar f = new fechar(this); //passe this
    f.ShowDialog();
    f.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Se funcionou, marca como resposta certa. :)

Comment: No construtor de fechar  você pode setar `frmParent.Opacity  = .75`, assim automaticamente quando você chamar o `fechar`, vai mudar a tela. Se você tiver um projeto com várias telas isto vai ser útil.

Comment: A resposta do @ramaral faz mais sentido.

Answer (score 5):

O propósito de um *Dialog* é obter uma resposta do usuário. 
O usuário responde escolhendo um dos botões disponíveis nele.

O método [ShowDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx) retorna um valor do tipo [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) cuja finalidade é indicar a resposta(botão) escolhida.

O valor retornado é o da propriedade [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) do *dialog*.

Use o valor retornado para saber qual foi o botão clicado e, caso seja `DialogResult.No`, colocar a opacidade a 1.

Form principal:

```
private void btFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = .75;
    fechar f = new fechar();
    if(f.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        this.Opacity = 1;
    }
    f.Dispose();
}
```

Dialog:

```
public void btFecharNAO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
    this.Close();
}
```

O método `btFecharNAO_Click()` pode, nesta situação, ser evitado se usar a propriedade [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) do botão.

Quando um botão tem a sua propriedade `DialogResult` com um valor diferente de `DialogResult.None` e pertença a uma *Form* aberta pelo método `ShowDialog()`, quando clicado fechará a *Form* sem necessidade de usar o respectivo evento, ao mesmo tempo a propriedade `DialogResult` da *Form* recebe o valor atribuído à propriedade `DialogResult` do botão.

Veja na documentação de [DialogResult Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) que outros valores pode atribuir ao `DialogResult`.